# sip.js / react / Получить причину завершения вызова

Tags: reactjs, sip

В гит проекте уже задал вопрос, но решил задать еще и здесь, мало ли кто знает и сможет подсказать :)

Использую react библиотеку

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sip.js

https://github.com/onsip/SIP.js/blob/master/docs/api/sip.js.md

Никак не могу найти способ, как получить причину завершения(SIP код) вызова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг кому будет полезно.
Устанавливается через делегат InviterInviteOptions.